# Maya Python windowPref command doesn't change window width, but says it does

Tags: python, user-interface, window, maya

I'm trying to set the width of a non-main Maya window (hypergraph, etc.).

But the command doesn't actually move it. It returns that it does...which is really weird. Anyone know what's up?

```
openWindows = cmds.lsUI(windows=True)

for i, window in enumerate(openWindows):
    if window != "MayaWindow":

        widthQueryPre = cmds.windowPref(window, q=True, w=True)

        cmds.windowPref(window, e=True, w=200) # Why doesn't this change the window's width?

        widthQueryPost = cmds.windowPref(window, q=True, w=True)

        print i, window, widthQueryPre, widthQueryPost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Maya 2014 documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/windowPref.html) (the version I'm using):

> Create or modify **preferred** window **attributes**. The size and position of
>   a window is retained during and between application sessions. A
>   **default window preference is created when a window is closed**. Window
>   preferences must be named and, consequently, only affect the window
>   with a matching name.

This means that the value you are changing using the `windowPref` command is not the actual size of the windows but it's default size. However this command is also called when you close a sub-window. And will override your previous calls to `windowPref`.
You have to call `windowPref` once your sub-window is closed. Then next time you'll open the sub-window it will be 200px width.

To sum up: This command **does not** resize your current sub-window but **sets it's default size**.

If you want to resize a current window, use the `window` command.

```
for win in cmds.lsUI(type="window"): #Lists all windows (including Pyside/PyQT ones)
    if win != "MayaWindow" and cmds.window(win, query=True, exists=True): #cmds.window(win, query=True, exists=True) checks if the windows really exists (do it, this can be useful)
        cmds.window( win, edit=True, widthHeight=(900, 777) ) #the actual command to resie the windows
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the explanation and example! Works great in 2016 as well.